# Crear driver propio en laravel 9

Tags: php, laravel, odbc, hana

Tengo un proyecto en Laravel 9 que se conecta a una base de datos HANA.

Por alguna razón que desconozco, el driver de odbc no funciona cuando utilizo PDO, pero si lo conecto usando odbc_pconnect no hay problemas. Mi idea entonces sería podeer usar las funcionalidades de Eloquent, pero para ello debo integrar la conexión a dicho ORM.

¿Como puedo crear un driver personalizado, para poder declararlo en database.php y poder usarlo?

Muchas gracias por los comentarios.

Comment: Deberías mostrar el código que estás tratando de usar para conectarte con PDO y odbc

Comment: Hola: En realidad no hay ninguno. Por ahora sólo es esto :

[code]
 'HANA' => [
            'driver'   => 'odbc',
            'dsn'      => env('SAP_DSN'),
           'database' => env('SAP_DB'),
            'username' => env('SAP_USER'),
            'password' => env('SAP_PASS')
        ]
[/code]
Para intentar implementar estaba usando esta librería, pero sin éxito. 

[enlace]https://github.com/appsfortableau/laravel-pdo-odbc[/enlace]

Comment: Entonces coloca el ejemplo que te sirve en odbc_pconnect en tu pregunta para saber lo que has hecho

Comment: En el caso de odbc_pconnect, puedo conectarme a la base de datos de HANA de esta forma : 

`
 putenv("DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/sap/hdbclient/libodbcHDB.so");
            putenv("ODBCINI=/etc/odbc.ini");
            $conector = odbc_pconnect(env('SAP_DSN'),env('SAP_USER'),env('SAP_PASS'),SQL_CUR_USE_DRIVER);
            $query=odbc_prepare($conector,$sql);
            $result=odbc_exec($conector,$sql) or die("ERRORNO=".odbc_error().", ERRORMSG=".odbc_errormsg());  
            return $result;
`

Comment: Bueno, leyendo lo que colocas, me da por pensar que al hacer putenv, es lo que hace que actives las librerías necesarias para conectarte a HANA. Ya tengo una idea más o menos cómo podrías crear un driver propio, pero tienes que asegurarte que tú sistema cuente con las librerías activadas, porque sino, igual fallará. Que es lo que creo que te está pasando